# ASP.NET MVC RouteConfig. Куда направлять, если в url указан только хост

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

RouteConfig.cs

```
   public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("Account/Login/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Account",
                url: "Login",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login"}
            );

            routes.MapRoute("Home", "{action}",
                new { controller = "Home" });

            routes.MapRoute("Error", "{controller}/{action}",
                new { controller = "Error" });
        }
    }
```

Работает так, как нужно. Но если в url содержится только лишь хост с потром, т.е. http://localhost:58370/, то я получаю 403.14. Не могу настроить, чтобы перенаправляло на контроллер "Test" и на action "Index".

Comment: cтандартный контроллер к маршруту `"{controller}/{action}"` у вас Error. cделайте Test, а action Index

Comment: `url : "/"` и `new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}`